# Cannot type pipe | on the atom terminal plugin

Tags: plugins, terminal, ide, character, atom-editor

I cannot type pipe `|` inside the terminal of atom. I have tried with several plugins `atom-terminal 0.80`, `platformio`, `terminal-plus`  and with all of them I have the same issue. It doesn't type anything.

The issue is only in the terminal pane not in the editor pane.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue, on Atom 1.54.0 on macOS